# Firebase and websocket extension vulnerability issue

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hey here anyone who can help me to fix firebase and websocket extension vulnerability issue.I am using latest version of firebase and websocket extension for push notification but still getting vulnerability issue in my project.is their anyone who can help me or guide me to resolve that issue

I tried to upgrade to latest version but still getting vulnerability issue i want to fix that vulnerability issue from firebase and websocket extension in my project

I m checking that vulnerability issue in soos where i m uploading package.json file and package-lock.json file and when i uploaded and it will scan that file and check whether any Library or dependency have vulnerability issue than in that i m getting vulnerability issue

[here is the image and see i m using latest version of firebase and webscoket extension both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pG4az.png)

Comment: can you provide how you know there's a vulnerability issue and which issue you are talking about?

Comment: I m checking that vulnerability issue in soos where i m uploading package.json file and package-lock.json file and when i uploaded and it will scan that file and check whether any Library or dependency have vulnerability issue than in that i m getting vulnerability issue

Comment: can you add this to your post please with the log

Comment: Is their any way to resolve this issue

Comment: I added image also please check that also